# pass value array for sectioned uitableview

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am facing difficulties on passing a value on array for sectioned UITableView

This code works well for me

```
LandingMenu *landing0 = [[LandingMenu alloc]init];
[landing0 setMenuTitle:@"For Verification"];
[landing0 setMenuTotalCount:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",20]];
[landing0 setMenuColorCode:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];

LandingMenu *landing6 = [[LandingMenu alloc]init];
[landing6 setMenuTitle:@"For Approval"];
[landing6 setMenuTotalCount:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",5]];
[landing6 setMenuColorCode:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];

_taskList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:landing0, landing6, nil];

LandingMenu *landing1 = [[LandingMenu alloc]init];
[landing1 setMenuTitle:@"Fund Transfer Own"];
[landing1 setMenuTotalCount:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",9]];
[landing1 setMenuType:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];

LandingMenu *landing2 = [[LandingMenu alloc]init];
[landing2 setMenuTitle:@"Fund Transfer Third Party"];
[landing2 setMenuTotalCount:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",5]];
[landing2 setMenuType:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];

LandingMenu *landing3 = [[LandingMenu alloc]init];
[landing3 setMenuTitle:@"Checkbook Reorder"];
[landing3 setMenuTotalCount:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",5]];
[landing3 setMenuType:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];

LandingMenu *landing4 = [[LandingMenu alloc]init];
[landing4 setMenuTitle:@"Stop Payment Order"];
[landing4 setMenuTotalCount:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",6]];
[landing4 setMenuType:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];

_forVerificationList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:landing1, landing2, landing4, nil];
_forApprovalList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:landing3, nil];

[_menuList addObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:landing1, landing2, landing4, nil]];
[_menuList addObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:landing3, nil]];
```

Now, i'm having a problem how to convert something like the one specified above having output. Assuming that this code came from a JSON object.

```
for (NSDictionary *dictCQ in taskJson) {
        NSLog(@"TASKLIST: %@", [dictCQ objectForKey:@"foTaskListModelWs"]);

        NSDictionary *datadic = [dictCQ objectForKey:@"foTaskListModelWs"];
        TaskList *task = [[TaskList alloc]init];
        [task setCount:datadic[@"count"]];
        [task setFuncCd:datadic[@"funcCd"]];
        [task setFuncCdDscp:datadic[@"funcCdDscp"]];
        [task setRequestStatus:datadic[@"requestStatus"]];
        [task setRole:datadic[@"role"]];
        [taskList addObject:task];
    }
```

Comment: Very hard to read your English...

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what you are trying to say?

Comment: my first code is only hard-coded. now, i'm getting my data on JSON.

Comment: Show the output of  NSLog(@"TASKLIST: %@", [dictCQ objectForKey:@"foTaskListModelWs"]);